# CSS - changes are not taken into account

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap to display a list and I am trying to customize its `list-item-component`.

I have the following code in my CSS file:

```
.list-group-item {
    border:0 !important;
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-bottom:2px;
}
```

I reference the CSS file like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="list.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Restriction Lists</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tree"></div>

<script src="ListApplication.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

The Bootstrap code is in the following file(I am using React).

```
  <script src="ListApplication.js"></script>
```

Another weird thing is that Chrome Developer Tools does not display the CSS file correctly.

Comment: Is your CSS file in the same directory as your html file?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `<meta>` first:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="list.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

and make sure jquery and bootstrap are coded succesfully in your `ListApplication.js`

it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was opening the HTML file from within Webstorm. When I was changing the CSS file, the changes were not loaded into the browser upon refresh.